# RecyclerView footer to fill parent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-appcompat

I have a `RecyclerView` with vertical `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`. My layout is very simple:

```
A   B 
 C1
 C2
 C3
 F
```

All items except **A** and **B** have `setFullSpan(true)` (set in `onCreateViewHolder()`). Often, there are enough **Cn** items to scroll up and down. In this case, **F** has its "natural" height, and all is well. But sometimes, there are not enough **C** items. In this case, I want the **F** view (before I switched from `ListView` to `RecyclerView`, it was my footer) to fill the screen, e.g.

```
A   B 
 C1
 C2

 F
```

I could not find a way to define this as `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.getItemOffsets()` because I don't see the position of my **F** view in when this method is called.

Also, it seems that `StaggeredGridLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPositions()` sometimes gives wrong answers.

BTW, I am testing on 4.4.2, so there may be problems with `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7`.